# Converting SMTP Sendgrid to Sendgrid API

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendgrid

Currently replacing the old SMTP Sendgrid to API Sendgrid and I noticed that there are some differences in their code.But I was thinking that since they are both sendgrid it will just work.  What I did is to add this                         `SendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(Message);` in the end. But it says

> cannot convert from system.net.mail.mailmessage to sendgrid.helpers.mail.sendgridmessage

Is this the correct way of converting it?

Below is the code.

```
        try
        {
            string SendGridKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridKey"];
            var SendGridClient = new SendGridClient(SendGridKey);
            using (MailMessage MessageContent = new MailMessage())
            {
                MessageContent.From = new MailAddress(From);
                MessageContent.To.Add(new MailAddress(To));
                MessageContent.Subject = Subject;
                MessageContent.Body = (TextBody);
                ContentType mimeType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html");
                AlternateView Alternate = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(HtmlBody, mimeType);
                Message.AlternateViews.Add(Alternate);
                if (AttachedFileName == true)
                {
                    Attachment AttachedFile = new Attachment(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "Path\\" + AttachedFileName);
                    MessageContent.Attachments.Add(AttachedFile);
                }

                //using (SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient())
                //{
                //    Client.EnableSsl = true;
                //    Client.Send(MessageContent);
                //}
                  SendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(Message);
            }
            return;
        }
```

Comment: You need to create an object of `sendgrid.helpers.mail.sendgridmessage` class and set it's properties and then pass it to `SendGridClient.SendEmailAsyc` method.

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-csharp-code-example/

Comment: I already did this. And I was able to successfully send an email. But I was hoping to just change a few line of code in the old smtp instead of creating a whole new one.

Comment: There is an issue opened on github for this ... https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/266 May be you can write your own implementation and help the community..

Answer (score 0):

For sending mail using SendGrid API, you need to create com.sendgrid.Request object. Adding code for java:

```
import com.sendgrid.Content;
import com.sendgrid.Email;
import com.sendgrid.Mail;
import com.sendgrid.Method;
import com.sendgrid.Request;
import com.sendgrid.SendGrid;

Email from = new Email("<FROM_EMAIL>");
String subject = "<SUBJECCT>";
Email to = new Email("<TO_EMAIL>");
Content content = new Content("text/plain", message);
Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);
SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(SendGridKey);
Request request = new Request();
try {
    request.setMethod(Method.POST);
    request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
    request.setBody(mail.build());
    sg.api(request);
    log.info("Main sent successfully");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    log.info("Error while sending mail: {}", ex.toString());
}
```